# Querying the database using EF Code First and Linq

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, ef-code-first

I've spent a good deal of time and can't figure out how to make this query work. I am making a hours of operation type module where the users can choose something like the following:

```
Monday open from 8am to 11am closed from 11am to 1pm and open from 1pm to 5pm
```

This is completely dynamic and the users can choose how many opens and close they want (dynamically generated form inputs)

To do this I have made a couple of classes (I have no idea if this is a proper way of doing this because I've been using asp.net mvc, C# and EF for about a week now. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated)

```
public class HoursOfOperation
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public IQueryable<CompanyHour> Monday { get; set; }
    public IQueryable<CompanyHour> Tuesday { get; set; }
    public IQueryable<CompanyHour> Wednesday { get; set; }
    public IQueryable<CompanyHour> Thursday { get; set; }
    public IQueryable<CompanyHour> Friday { get; set; }
    public IQueryable<CompanyHour> Saturday { get; set; }
    public IQueryable<CompanyHour> Sunday { get; set; }

    //Navigation Property
    public CompanyInformation Company { get; set; }

}
```

and

```
public class CompanyHour
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public Status Status { get; set; }
    public string From { get; set; }
    public string To { get; set; }
}

public enum Status
{
    Closed,
    Open,
    ByAppointmentsOnly
}
```

for completeness here is my companyInformation class

```
public class CompanyInformation
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int id { get; set; }

    //[Required]
    [DisplayName("Company Name:")]
    public string companyName { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Website Address:")]
    [Url(ErrorMessage="The Website field is not a valid fully-qualified http, https, or ftp URL. (Example: http://www.website.com)")]
    public string website { get; set; }
    public string contactTitle { get; set; }

    //[Required]
    [DisplayName("Contact First Name:")]
    public string contactFirstName { get; set; }
    //[Required]
    [DisplayName("Contact Last Name:")]
    public string contactLastName { get; set; }

    //[Required]
    [Phone]
    [DisplayName("Phone Number:")]
    public string contactPhoneNumber { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Address Display?")]
    public bool displayAddress { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Phone Number?")]
    public bool displayPhoneNumber { get; set; }

    //[Required]
    [DisplayName("Address 1:")]
    public string address1 { get; set; } 
    [DisplayName("Address 2:")]
    public string address2 { get; set; }

    //[Required]
    [DisplayName("City:")]
    public string city { get; set; }

    //[Required]
    [DisplayName("State:")]
    public string state { get; set; }

    //[Required]
    [DisplayName("Zip/Postal Code:")]
    public string zipCode { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Search Engine?")]
    public bool allowSearchEngines { get; set; }


    //navigation Properties
    public virtual ICollection<UserProfile> CompanyUsers { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<HoursOfOperation> CompanyHours { get; set; }


}
```

The reason, I have hardcoded the monday, tue.... in the hoursofoperation class is to make it easy for mvc to map the dynamically generated fields (and that part works!!! :) )

Now I want to query the database and make a hours of operations model to send back to the view (on get) so I can bring back the saved information. I however can't figure out how to do that. I'm sending back a HoursOfOperation class.

the query I have currently:

```
var model = company.CompanyHours.Where(e => e.Company.id == company.id);
```

just returns a HoursOfOperation model with only the id (correct id) all the companyHours entities are all null.

Can anyone help me come up with the proper query?

Comment: Have you set Lazyloading to false? If that's the case you have to load'em by your self

Comment: @websam I have removed the `virtual` keyword and have disabled LazyLoading in the context and am getting the same result.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to do this make use of `InClude` method to get the child enitities

```
context.Companies
             .Include("CompanyHours")
             .Where(e => e.Company.id == company.id) ;
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I get the same result

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I finally fixed this problem but the way I did it was completely restructure my models to a better and correct design.